# Cannot check in changes to Tortoise after Copy/Replace of files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I got latest from a restored repository.

Took only the files from my collegue's PC, copy/replaced some files (no not svn files, I left those in tact) to that repository restore that I checked out locally.  Tried to check back in and appeared to go through.  But I updated then looked at history and they are not there.

Why?

Comment: When you checked in your changes, did the window that pops up to show your progress show those files as committed updated?

Comment: yes, and it showed successful.  I think after looking at this again, it's just the that history isn't showing the commit

Comment: In fact I just created a new test.txt, checked it in.  No trace in the log.  Remember I restored an older repository, checked it out and did this to it.  Why wouldn't it show histroy?

Comment: I noticed the date range in the log window only allows me to see up to the 15th of this month.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it does that no idea why but you can avoid new files being problematic by right button dragging and choosing SVN copy and add. When moving files copy them out of workspace delete using Tortoise menu and add to the desired location to avoid any trouble.

Comment: but this is a newly restored repo with a repo # that's not synced with my collegue's old local copy.  If I do svn copy, I would be attempting to retain repo version that is incompatible with the restored repo I'm copying to.